# How to find and print arguments of a command in ps?

Tags: shell, ps, process-management

`sudo ps o gpid,comm` reports something like `3029 bash` but the command has parameters `--arbitrary -other -searchword` is there a way to display these arguments?

Comment: Whats wrong with `ps -ef` ?

Comment: Yeah the point is actually just to get the pgids but grep on the arguments to find the right ones. So with an awk command ps -ef should would the same. Ill ask more specific questions moving forward

Comment: In that case the easier would be `pgrep -a bash` ..check it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than formatting the output of `ps` and then using `grep`, you can simply use `pgrep` with `-a` option:

```
pgrep -a bash
```

This will show the command name (`bash`) along with its arguments (if any).

From `man pgrep` :

```
-a, --list-full
              List the full command line as well as the process ID.
```

Comment: actually I used your suggestion in my follow up:     http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213159/kill-processes-in-one-line-with-kill-awk-ps-and-grep

Comment: @ChrisHannon I am glad it worked for you  :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't have to grep anything when using `ps` (at least the procps-ng implementation typically found on GNU/Linux systems, or the HP-UX `ps`), run this:

```
ps -o args= -C bash
```

If the list of arguments is very long, you may throw in a couple of `-w` options (though not on HP-UX):

```
ps -wwo args= -C bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command:

```
sudo ps o gpid,comm,args
```

will print:

```
3029 bash       bash --arbitrary -other -searchword
```

Comment: i had to drop gpid in favor of pid