# killing a process in one line

Tags: process, kill

Sometimes I need to end a process quickly via terminal but it is tedious to just type `ps -e | grep firefox` and then kill  all the time. I want to create an `alias` in my .bashrc and just type in `killfirefox`

I guess [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213159/kill-processes-in-one-line-with-kill-awk-ps-and-grep) would do it but I don't really understand everything.

so I've learn that either `ps -e | grep firefox | sudo awk '{print $1}'` 
or `pgrep firefox` will return the pid of firefox which I need to kill a process. I thought this would do the job :

`pgrep firefox | sudo awk '{kill $1}'` but it doesn't work. It says nothing and firefox is still running. I then tried `pgrep firefox | sudo awk '{system(sudo kill $1)}'` but then it returns "sh: 1: 27762: not found".

Why doesn't my way work? What's wrong?

Comment: your way doesn't work because it makes no sense.  it's both wrong and massively over-complicated (e.g. why do you think you need `sudo` to kill a process you own?).  BTW, if you have `pgrep`, you also have `pkill`.

Comment: You also could try `killall firefox` or `killall -r firefox`.

Comment: Upvoting this. Because overkill can be instructive sometimes. In French we call it "chercher midi à quatorze heures".

Answer (score 6):

To have your way works you have to fix the awk syntax and use the system function to execute commands in awk:

```
pgrep firefox | awk '{system("kill "$1)}'
```

Then you have your own-made (wheel reinvented) equivalent of:

```
pkill firefox
```

as pointed out in your question comments.

Answer (score 1):

For applications like Firefox, I just use `killall firefox`.

[man killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

Answer (score -2):

can you try creating an alias of this

ps -U root -u root | grep "$2" | sudo awk '{system ("sudo kill "$2)}'

Comment: This is even more typing than the OP already was doing

Comment: original command by OP > ps -e | grep firefox | sudo awk '{print $1}'